SimpleSamlPhp in PHP8.3 or PHP8.4 (Windows IIS)
I'm trying to upgrade an existing code base from PHP 7 to 8.
Now one of the most important external packages is SimpleSamlPhp. The current code uses v1.19, but the latest version is 2.3.5.
Now I want to use this latest version, but then, on both 8.4 and 8.3, I get warnings from preg_match:

PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: PCRE2 does not support \F, \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 17 in...

First, I learned that there are compatibility issues with PHP 8.4, but the issue doesn't disappear when reverting to PHP 8.3. The docs on SimpleSaml state that the requirement for PHP is >= 8.1, so am I doing anything wrong here?
I could go into the code of SimpleSaml to fix the regex, but I don't like to do so because it's an external package.
The code base isn't mine, I'm an external employee trying to get this code up and running in PHP 8, without any knowledge of the internals of the application, yet.

I get warnings from preg_match...are these warnings pointing to code within the SimpleSaml library? You've omitted the  stack trace from your question.
